# Convert select to text inputs after AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

How can I replace the select drop down with input text fields while fetching data from database using the AJAX `success` function?

```
success: function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  $('select[name="city"]').empty();
  $('select[name="Metatags"]').empty();
  $('select[name="Description"]').empty();

  $.each(data, function (key, value) {
    $('select[name="city"]').append('<option value="' + value.page_title + '">' + value.page_title + '</option>');
    $('select[name="Metatags"]').append('<option value="' + value.page_metatags + '">' + value.page_metatags + '</option>');
    $('select[name="Description"]').append('<option value="' + value.page_decription + '">' + value.page_decription + '</option>');
  });
}
```

Comment: What's the issue here?

Comment: $('select[name="city"]').append('<option value="' + value.page_title + '">' + value.page_title + '</option>'); values displaying in drop down list i want to display in input text fileds

Comment: You want one of them being "selected" after $.each() ?

Comment: yes..i want display the values in text fields instead of select drop down list

Comment: Then I guess you need to create (if not created before) the html inputs with the values coming from the AJAX request and append them to a container, perhaps the same one used for the drop down... And I guess you will also want to hide the drop down list. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure following input text field in your html page

```
<input type="text" name="city" />
<input type="text" name="Metatags" />
<input type="text" name="Description" />
```

then, add following jquery codes inside the success callback function

```
var title = [], metatags = [], decription = [];
$.each(data, function (key, value){
    title.push(value.page_title); metatags.push(value.page_metatags); decription.push(value.page_decription);                
});
$('input[name="city"]').val(title.join(','));
$('input[name="Metatags"]').val(metatags.join(','));
$('input[name="Description"]').val(decription.join(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a reputation to comment.

You can add three hidden text fields. Show them after getting the response and hide the selects.Then append data into text fields.

```
var page_title_text = '';
var page_metatags_text = '';
var page_decription_text = '';
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    page_title_text = page_title_text+', '+ value.page_title;
    page_metatags_text = page_metatags_text+', '+value.page_metatags+;
    page_decription_text = page_decription_text+', '+value.page_decription;
});
$('input[name="city"]').val(page_title_text);
$('input[name="Metatags"]').val(page_metatags_text);
$('input[name="Description"]').val(page_decription_text);
```

Hope it will help you or let me know your question clearly so that I can help you.

Comment: empty text fields displaying

Comment: I updated my answer kindly try it. Happy if I can help you let me know if the problem is not solved.

Comment: Ok, I did not use the array. @Anfath Hifans solution is more optimized.

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
 var Title;
        var MetaTags;
        var Desc;
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('select[name="city"]').empty();
            $('select[name="Metatags"]').empty();
            $('select[name="Description"]').empty();

            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                $('select[name="city"]').append('<option value="' + value.page_title + '">' + value.page_title + '</option>');
                $('select[name="Metatags"]').append('<option value="' + value.page_metatags + '">' + value.page_metatags + '</option>');
                $('select[name="Description"]').append('<option value="' + value.page_decription + '">' + value.page_decription + '</option>');
                Title = value.page_title ;
                MetaTags = value.page_metatags ;
                Desc = value.page_decription ;
            });

            $("#yourTextboxId").val(Title);
            $("#yourTextboxId").val(MetaTags);
            $("#yourTextboxId").val(Desc);
        }
```

Comment: you can declare variables as globaly.